# Quasar Table - custom cursor is overriden by @row-click event

Tags: quasar

In a quasar table there is an event "row-click" that if handled changes mouse cursor to pointer and enables row-clicking.

I have a common table used by many components. I want to selectively disable the pointer style if a rowClick prop passed to it is false.

I currently have this code to disable the row-click handler if rowClick prop is false.

```
@row-click="rowClick ? handleRowClick : null"
```

I've tried setting a :table-style but the @row-click still overrides it.

How do I change the cursor style based on a prop?